# Why can I not set -[UITableView alwaysBounceVertical] with IB?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I have a UITableView that I do not want to bounce when there are not enough cells in the table to warrant scrolling. Therefore, I set `-bounces` to YES and `-alwaysBounceVertical` to NO.

I try to set these properties with IB, using the "Bounces" and "Bounce Vertically" checkboxes, but it seems that no matter what I set the Bounce Vertically property to in IB, it is always YES at runtime.

I would much rather be able to fully configure this with IB and not require setting the property with code. Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Comment: I think you need to use code. You could try `tableView.bounces = NO;`

Comment: @WarifAkhandRishi - Just setting -bounces to NO would turn off bouncing in all cases. I am looking to bounce only when scrolling is necessary. -bounces=YES and -alwaysBounceVertical=NO does exactly what I want, but although it appears to be possible with IB, table views configured this way with IB seem to ignore the "Bounce Vertically" checkbox setting, always setting -alwaysBounceVertical to YES.

Answer (score 6):

Setting the 'Bounces Vertically' checkbox in Interface Builder seems to be broken. I have found however that you can set alwaysBounceVertical as a 'User Defined Runtime Attribute' in IB and it does work.

(Xcode 5.0.1 iOS7 SDK)

Comment: @KeithSmiley, thank you for filing radar://22959792 about this! Since iOS 7, UITableView always sets the value to YES on init, even when it is unarchived from a nib/storyboard. I've submitted a simple fix for review. If only someone had reported this earlier, perhaps it could have been fixed earlier. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you want in the interface builder. Rather you have to implement this simple code to do the required task.

You need to set "Bounces" property to NO instead of YES and "Bounce Vertically" to YES in the Interface Builder. To enable the bounce when there are more cells you can use this code:

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        NSInteger iRows = [arraytableData count];

        if(tableView.visibleCells.count < iRows)
        {
            tableView.bounces = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            tableView.bounces = NO;
        }
        return iRows;
    }
```

Comment: This code is unnecessary; setting -bounces to YES and -alwaysBounceVertical to NO one time during -viewDidLoad is sufficient to accomplish my goal. I was trying to avoid even this small amount of code via configuration in IB, but discovered that the "Bounce Vertically" checkbox in IB has no effect on the table view at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue at the time of page load it always bounces vertically UITableView. After long searching I got solution.
  I am making custom navigation bar using image in Xib and putting UITableView before UIImageView in UIView placeholders.
  Then I have changed position of UITableView in UIView placeholders and below code works for me `self.tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;`
If anybody have this type of issue so please double check the position of UITableView in placeholders. Thanks